# ERROR in the transition system (act) Circumstance in JaCaMo / Jason

Tags: agent, multi-agent

I am experiencing an error when trying to send an untell message. I have wrote a simple project to explain: When bob is sending an untell message an error in transition system is occurring. Is it possible to remove a belief by untell? So, how to send it?

Bob's code:

```
!start.

+!start <- 
    .print("Starting...");
    .send(alice, tell, hi).

+hi <- 
    .print("Hi");
    .send(alice, tell, marryMe).

+yes <-
    .print("No no..."); 
    .send(alice, untell, marryMe).


{ include("$jacamoJar/templates/common-cartago.asl") }
{ include("$jacamoJar/templates/common-moise.asl") }
```

Alice's code:

```
+hi <- 
    .print("Hi");
    .send(bob, tell, hi).

+marryMe <- 
    .print("Yes!");
    .send(bob, tell, yes).

-marryMe <- .print("Humm?").

{ include("$jacamoJar/templates/common-cartago.asl") }
{ include("$jacamoJar/templates/common-moise.asl") }
```

Project:

```
mas jacamotest {

    agent bob

    agent alice

}
```

Jacamo's output:

> ```
> CArtAgO Http Server running on http://X.X.X.X:3273
> Jason Http Server running on http://X.X.X.X:3272
> [bob] Starting...
> [alice] Hi
> [bob] Hi
> [alice] Yes!
> [bob] No no...
> [ArithExpr] The value of (-NS::CA) is not a number! Unifier = {Sender=bob, NS=default, Content=marryMe, _42=mid5,
> CA=marryMe[source(bob)]}. Code: kqmlPlans.asl:43
> [alice] *** ERROR in the transition system (act). Circumstance:
>   E =[]
>   I =[]
>   A =null
>   MB=[]
>   RP=null
>   AP=null
>   SE=+!kqml_received(bob,untell,marryMe,mid5)
>   SO=(@kqmlReceivedUnTell[source(self)] +!kqml_received(Sender,untell,NS::Content,_42) <- .add_nested_source(Content,Sender,CA); -(-NS::CA).,{Sender=bob,
>   NS=default, Content=marryMe, _42=mid5, CA=marryMe[source(bob)]})
>   SI=intention 6: 
>     +!kqml_received(bob,untell,marryMe,mid5) <- ... -(-NS::CA) / {Sender=bob, NS=default, Content=marryMe, _42=mid5,
>   CA=marryMe[source(bob)]}
>
>   AI=null
>   AE=null
>   PA={}
>   PI={}
>   FA=[].
> Creating a new C!
> java.lang.ClassCastException: jason.asSyntax.NumberTermImpl cannot be cast to jason.asSyntax.Literal
>   at jason.asSemantics.TransitionSystem.prepareBodyForEvent(TransitionSystem.java:932)
>   at jason.asSemantics.TransitionSystem.applyExecInt(TransitionSystem.java:907)
>   at jason.asSemantics.TransitionSystem.applySemanticRuleAct(TransitionSystem.java:237)
>   at jason.asSemantics.TransitionSystem.act(TransitionSystem.java:1525)
>   at jason.infra.centralised.CentralisedAgArch.act(CentralisedAgArch.java:203)
>   at jason.infra.centralised.CentralisedAgArch.reasoningCycle(CentralisedAgArch.java:212)
>   at jason.infra.centralised.CentralisedAgArch.run(CentralisedAgArch.java:231)
>   at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

It is due to a bug in the SNAPSHOT version. The new jason-2.3-SNAPSHOT is fixing it.